# Control Multiple session for Same User

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Trying to implement concurrent Session Control to invalidate the prior logged-in session and logout that session and let user login on another browser, so that a single user concurrently do not have multiple logins. I have used the following HTTP configurations in Web security configurations. But it's not working.

***UaaWebSecurityconfiguration.java***

```
 @Autowired
    public   SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        if (sessionRegistry == null) {
            sessionRegistry = new SessionRegistryImpl();
        }
        return sessionRegistry;
    }

@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, CsrfFilter.class).exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport).accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
            .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .key(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getRememberMe()
                .getKey()).and().headers()
            .frameOptions().disable()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry)
            .and()
            .sessionFixation()
            .changeSessionId()
            .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy())
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/register")
            .permitAll().antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll().antMatchers("/api/authenticate")
            .permitAll().antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/profile-info").permitAll().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/websocket/tracker").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/websocket/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/configuration/ui").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy() {
        ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy strategy = new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry());
        strategy.setMaximumSessions(1);
        return strategy;
    }

    @Bean

    public SessionFixationProtectionStrategy sessionFixationProtectionStrategy(){
        return new SessionFixationProtectionStrategy();
    }

    @Bean

    public RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy(){
        RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy = new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry());
        return registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
    }


    @Bean
    public CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy(){
        List<SessionAuthenticationStrategy> sessionAuthenticationStrategies = new ArrayList<>();
        sessionAuthenticationStrategies.add(concurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy());
        sessionAuthenticationStrategies.add(sessionFixationProtectionStrategy());
        sessionAuthenticationStrategies.add(registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy());
        CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy = new CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategies);
        return compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With this configuration, a session will be created in only one browser,
and all attempts to login to the new browser will not be successful as long as the session exists.

With such a minimal configuration:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
    }
```

the session will be created every time, and the old session will expired